# Are there any ways of using the graphics card (apart from CUDA and OpenCL)?

Tags: c++, gpu

I'm pretty new in GPU programming and I haven't heard of any other way (apart from CUDA and OpenCL) to use the video board, so I'm wondering if there are other ways to use it. Can anybody point me to some examples?

And one more question :D:
Do OpenGL and DirectX take advantage of the graphics card? If yes, can you please tell me how?

P.S: I use C++.

Edit: Thank you for your fast replies.

As far as I know, the graphics card is used for parallel processing (Same Instruction Multiple Data especially). If you mentioned it, I would also like to know whether there are also other kind of uses of the graphics card (especially for the older ones, since they don't support OpenCL and CUDA, I guess they can't do parallel processing).

Answer (score 2):

Addional GPGPU Languages/Stanadards

[Brook](http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/brookgpu/)

[OpenACC](http://www.openacc-standard.org/)

[OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/)

> And one more question :D: Do OpenGL and DirectX take advantage of the
>   graphics card? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Before the introduction of shaders, the rendering processes were implemented
sequentially by fixed-function circuits.After Shader Model was introduced, vertex shader processors and pixel shader processors were added to replace thefixed-function blocks.
Now each stream core is unified shader proccessor ,which can run Vertex/Geometry/Pixel Shader as well as  Hull and Doman Shader ,itroduced in DirectX11 and aslo Compute Shaders -Kernels.Thus, the full capacity of the shaders can be used at all times,maximizing shader performance efficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm pretty new in GPU programming and I haven't heard of any other way (apart from CUDA and OpenCL) to use the video board

There's OpenCL and OpenMP. ATI also had some kind of API(I think), but I forgot what it is called.

> Do OpenGL and DirectX take advantage of the graphics card?

Of course they do. DirectX in particular was designed to provide more-or-lesss easy access to hardware acceleration. You can't perform rendering on CPU with the same speed.

> , I would also like to know whether there are also other kind of uses of the graphics card

If the card supports floating point textures, you can use fragment/pixel shaders in conjuction with those textures to perform some calculations on the GPU even if GPU doesn't support CUDA/OpenCL/whatever. I *think* technique was called GDGPU. DirectX sdk had "GPU cloth" example a while ago, and in NVidia OpenGL SDK there are ["GDGPU fluid" and "GPU particles"](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/samples.html). Please note that trying to perform overly expensive computation (like performing exhaustive search on 4096x4096 texture for every pixel rendered) on the GPU this way can bluescreen the system on certain hardware.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL, OpenGL, DirectX and, to a certain extent, CUDA are just interface specifications which a hardware vendor can implement in a driver. These interfaces can then bus used to utilize whatever is driven by the driver. In most cases, this is a GPU for these interfaces. There are other interfaces (WDDM specifies more interfaces) to talk to a GPU but they all have certain use cases. 
You might want to clarify what you mean by "using the grahpics card".